# How to build a SIP & VOIP app for android?

Tags: android, sip

Can any one tell me the correct usage of portsip sdk usage

I could initialize the sdk but couldn't establish the call session.

sip server details :
        userName = "varmach";
        password = "6UButR6rxsbaFz2y";
        SIPServer= "varmach@getonsip.com";
        SIPPort= "5060";
        userDomain= "getonsip.com";
        authName= "getonsip_varmach";

address i used to call the other android device is : sip:anantha@getonsip.com

but -1 is returned while establishing the session .

Please specify the correct format of address if anyone knows.

Answer (score 2):

-1 is returned means it failed to create session,check the server settings.auth name and domain are optional ,dont give them for the moment.Usually sip server should  be some no.s for e.g;80.442.243.8 something like this.